# How to use AND on the same entity?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I want to get the names of the workers that did orders on day x AND day y.

```
select name
from worker,
     orders
 where worker.workerid = oders.workerid
   and date = x and date = y;
```

So I want only to get the workers that did orders on both days.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Hi. If you want things that are tall & things that are short, does that mean you want things that are tall & short? No. Just because a word pops into your head it doesn't mean you should stop thinking. PS This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. Also hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Show parts you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in (x,y)` will get you the workers that worked in at least one of the 2 days.

While this one here will get you those who worked 2 distinct days.

```
group by name
having count(distinct date)=2
```

In total you get what you want

```
select name
from worker,
     orders
 where worker.workerid = oders.workerid
   and date in (x,y)
group by name
having count(distinct date)=2
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail, if a worker has 2 orders on X and 1 on Y (so 3 in Total?) If so, maybe worth mentioning. Also 2 orders on "X" would match the having-condition?

Comment: added the distinct

Answer (score 1):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to make sure both dates are there.

```
select name
from worker
join orders
    on worker.workerid = orders.workerid
where date in (x, y)
group by name
having count(distinct date) >= 2
```

Note the switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax!

Comment: Using count distinct at the HAVING is a bad approach... especially if you'er already using group by

Comment: I agree completly, by not adding DISTINCT after the group, it overkill... I fixed my own answer

Comment: @GuyL: the `distinct` **is** necessary unless `name, date` is defined as unique in the table.

Comment: I didn't say it wan't needed, I just said that this is a wrong use of it... group by and having are enough for this specific case...

Comment: @GuyL: no, it's not wrong. It's required. See here for an example: http://rextester.com/JGWSK57293

Answer (score 1):

Using two exists where clauses...

```
SELECT name 
FROM worker AS w
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM orders AS o 
    WHERE w.workerid = o.workerid
    AND date = x)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM orders AS o 
    WHERE w.workerid = o.workerid
    AND date = y)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is to use 2 partial queries and the postgre `Intersect` operator:

```
select name
from worker,
     orders
 where worker.workerid = oders.workerid
   and date = y
INTERSECT
select name
from worker,
     orders
 where worker.workerid = oders.workerid
   and date = x;
```

This will leave only worker names, that have been active at `X` AND `y`.

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-intersect/

> Like the UNION and EXCEPT operators, the PostgreSQL INTERSECT operator
>   combines the result sets of two or more SELECT statements into a
>   single result set. The INTERSECT operator returns any rows that are
>   available in both result set or returned by both queries.

Comment: INTERSECT, nice. Will work well as long as no more dates are added.

Comment: @jarlh well, if the query is generated programmatically, you can intersect `n` queries, as long as you don't exceed the max query length.

Comment: Of course. What about performance? I suppose each added INTERSECT will read the table one more time?

Comment: @jarlh That's another Topic. Also it really depends on, if it is required to have more dates (or lets say: an unknown amount of dates) to be added. Not saying this is the best / only solution, it is just the simplest way while keeping "nice readability".

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
SELECT name from worker, orders 
WHERE worker.workerid = oders.workerid
    DATE date IN (x, y)
```

Comment: This is not what Im looking fore because when I use "in" I get also the workers that worked only on day x or on day y but I only need the workers that worked on both days.